# Problems with libRblas.so on ubuntu with rpy2

Tags: r, python

I try to install rpy2 in my system,
(I compile R with --enable-R-shlib and with --enable-BLAS-shlib flags)
but when I try in python console

```
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in<module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py",
 line 14, in<module>
      import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py",
 line 75, in<module>
      from rpy2.rinterface.rinterface import *
 ImportError: libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file
 or directory
```

The rpy2 directory is:

```
rpy2.__path__

['/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2']
```

My R version is:

```
R version 2.12.1 Patched (2011-01-04 r53913)
```

My R home is:

```
/usr/bin/R
```

My ubuntu version is:

```
Linux kenneth-desktop 2.6.32-27-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 00:51:09 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My Python version is:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
```

When I install rpy2 from source (sudo python setup.py build install)
I got:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Configuration for R as a library:
   include_dirs: ('/usr/lib64/R/include',)
   libraries: ('R', 'Rblas', 'Rlapack')
   library_dirs: ('/usr/lib64/R/lib',)
   extra_link_args: ()
  # OSX-specific (included in extra_link_args)
   framework_dirs: ()
   frameworks: ()
running install
running install_lib
running install_data
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2-2.1.9.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rpy2-2.1.9.egg-info
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you tried to do things locally but didn't quite get there. I happen to maintain the Debian packages of R (which get rebuilt for Ubuntu and are accessible at [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/). These builds use external BLAS.  rpy2 then builds just fine as well.

I would recommend that you read the [README](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), try to install `r-base-core` and `r-base-dev` from the repositories and then try to install `rpy2` from source.  Or live with the slightly older `rpy2` package in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

For others running into this issue, I was able to solve it by making sure to add the R libraries to my library path in bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="R-install-location/lib65/R/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```